# left and right objects are evaluated / resolved during runtime or compile-time?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Referring to a book exercise...

Having the following code..

```java
Left left = createLeftInstance ();
Right right = createRightInstance ();
```

...and keeping in consideration that both the above mentioned methods can return instance of all the sub-classes of Left and Right, in Java the call of the following method...

```java
left.invoke (right);
```

how is resolved:

- A) basing on runtime type of left and compile-time of right
- B) basing on compile-time type of left and runtime of right
- C) basing on compile-time type of left and compile-time of right
- D) basing on runtime type of left and runtime of right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) is the correct answer here.

The following code demonstrates that.

```
    public class Main001 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A right = createRightInstance();
            B left = createLeftInstance();

            left.invoke(right);
            System.out.println("Done!!!");
        }

        public static B createLeftInstance() {
            return new B2();
        }

        public static A createRightInstance() {
            return new A2();
        }

    }

    class A{

    }

    class A1 extends A{

    }

    class A2 extends A1{

    }

    class B{
        public void invoke(A x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A on B with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
        public void invoke(A1 x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A1 on B with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
        public void invoke(A2 x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A2 on B with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    class B1 extends B{
        public void invoke(A x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A on B1 with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
        public void invoke(A1 x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A1 on B1 with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
        public void invoke(A2 x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A2 on B1 with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }

    }

    class B2 extends B1{
        public void invoke(A x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A on B2 with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
        public void invoke(A1 x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A1 on B2 with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
        public void invoke(A2 x) {
            System.out.println("Invoking method A2 on B2 with argument " + x.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

This example prints

```
Invoking method A on B2 with argument A2
Done!!!
```

which means A) is the correct answer.

Why does it mean that?

Well... because:
1) a method from the B2 class is invoked (as the output says) and B2 is the runtime type of `left` (the compile time type of `left` is B).
2) a method with parameter A is invoked (note that A is the compile-time type of `right`), even though the runtime type of `right` is A2. Compile time type of `right` is just the type with which `right` is declared i.e. A. Runtime type of `right` is the actual type of the argument i.e. A2 (see the output, it says `with argument A2` there).

Comment: NP. Hope you understood it. It's good to know such things in depth otherwise some programs you code may work in a completely different way than you expect them to work :) This is a basic but nice and tricky question.

Comment: I think i got it, but not 100% sure. Tomorrow i will probably pass hours on this; surely I will not move on to the next one without understand this (this would not be in the dna of a programmer). If i will need additional support i will come back to you ahah. Really thank you!!!

Comment: You can always re-read it, play with some similar examples yourself. This question is about polymorphism. I am sure many experienced developers may answer incorrectly to it. Roughly speaking the answer may be formulated as: you have polymorphism on the reference which you call (`left`) but not on the argument which you pass in (`right`). Maybe that's the simple way to remember this rule.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think that the technically correct answer is "none of the above".

- At compile time, you need to know the declared types of the `left` variable (`Left`) and the `right` variable (`Right`).  This will determine which method overload<sup>1</sup> of the `Left::invoke` method is most applicable to a parameter of type `Right`.
- At runtime, the actual type of `left` will determine which actual method gets called.

So the complete answer is:

> E) based on compile-time AND runtime types of `left` and on the compile-time type of `right`.

However, I suspect that the point of this question in the textbook is to help you distinguish between compile-time resolution of non-overloaded methods and runtime method dispatching.  For that purpose, A) is "correct enough".

---

<sup>1 - To make the determination, the compiler needs to compare `Right` and its supertypes with the different method overloads of the `invoke` method declared by `Left` and its supertypes.   If there are multiple overloads, the compiler needs to choose the "most specific applicable" overload.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Java has **A**, it is called *single dispatch*:

- the method overload is selected by the compiler, at compile-time (matching the compile-time type of `right` to the methods offered by the compile-time type of `left`)
- the method invocation happens on the runtime type of `left` - as methods do not disappear, `left` certainly has a method with the same signature which was picked at compile-time. This act counts as "dispatch", and as it only depends on `left` (in runtime), it is "single".

Super simple demo using built-in `println(Object)` and `println(char[])`:

```
char c[]={'a','b','c'};
System.out.println(c);
Object o=c;
System.out.println(o);
```

It [results](https://ideone.com/2tm4ny) in something like

> ```
> abc
> [C@1540e19d
> ```

The first line shows that `println(char[])` concatenates the array of characters, the second line shows that the exact same array (one can add some check like `println(o==c);`) passed as `Object` in compile-time results in invoking the `println(Object)` overload, regardless of the runtime type.

**B** and **C** probably do not exist.

**D** is called *multiple dispatch*, when the method signature is also selected in runtime using the actual runtime type of the arguments, and the selected method is invoked on the runtime type of `left`. Java does not support that by default, it can be implemented using reflection, here is a single-argument example:

```
public static void trickyprintln(Object o) throws Exception {
    System.out.getClass().getMethod("println",o.getClass()).invoke(System.out,o);
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    char c[]={'a','b','c'};
    trickyprintln(c);
    Object o=c;
    trickyprintln(o);
}
```

This one [results](https://ideone.com/Eb4pGs) in

> ```
> abc
> abc
> ```

as `println` is picked manually, using the runtime type of the argument. So it is possible to do if someone really needs it in Java, but it does not happen automatically.